# Un-representable DateTime for Year, Month and Day

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datetimepicker

I have two DateTimePicker boxes where the user can choose a "Date From" and "Date To". When a checkBox is clicked then the values in both boxes get the format "MMM", so just the month gets displayed (for example: Dec). Now I have the following Linq statement in my code which searches in a DataTable:

```
if (checkSearchMonth.Checked)
{
  DateDt.CaseSensitive = false;
   //DateDt = my DataTable
  var rowSources = DateDt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(myRow => myRow.Field<DateTime>(getSelectedItem).Month > pickDateFrom.Value.Month)
 //getSelectedItem = Column name
    .Where(myRow => myRow.Field<DateTime>(getSelectedItem).Month < pickDateTo.Value.Month)
    .OrderBy(myRow => myRow.Field<DateTime>(getSelectedItem));

if (rowSources.Any())
  dataGridPrev.DataSource = rowSources.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

My DateTimePickers both have a ShowUpDown. Now when I increase from 'Dec' to 'Jan' in my From-DateTimePicker everything works fine. Increasing the value to 'Feb' causes an Exception (see the topic). This happens at

```
     Application.Run(new Form1());
```

in my Program.cs. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dec 31 -> Jan 31 is fine.

Jan 31 -> Feb 31 will give you the exception.

Comment: How to avoid this in my case?

Comment: When they check the box, set the DatePicker to the first of the month of the currently selected Date: new DateTime(x.Year, x.Month, 1)

Comment: Have a look at whatever is generating dates that aren't possible (for example, February 31.) The invalid date is coming from *somewhere*.

Comment: Great! That helped and worked fine! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

February 31 its going to fail for obvious reasons.

try put a "try catch" and see the true exception and put validation in the field

Comment: The try-catch block didn't give me any new information but now it is solved. Thanks!